Error en MongoDB Serverless pero no en el Plan Gratuito 'TypeError: Cannot pin multiple connections to the same session'
Estoy experimentando un problema con mi aplicación que utiliza Mongoose y MongoDB. El error específico que estoy encontrando es
TypeError:  Cannot pin multiple connections to the same session {"stack":"TypeError: Cannot pin multiple connections to the same session\n    at ClientSession.pin
Este problema sólo se produce cuando utilizo el plan MongoDB serverless. Cuando cambio al plan gratuito, el error no aparece. La arquitectura de mi aplicación y el código de manejo de sesiones son los mismos en ambos casos. He aquí una versión simplificada de mi código
await session.withTransaction(async () => {
  if (mercanciaActualizar.length > 0) {
    const importador = actividad?.cliente_razon_social
    await actualizarVehiculosParaDespacho(
      mercanciaaActualizar.operaciones,
      mercanciaaActualizar.mercancia,
      idActividad,
      importador,
      session
    )
    // mercanciasDeLaActividad = mercanciasDeLaActividad.concat(actualizada)
  })

En esta parte del código es donde ocurre el error
const actualizarListaVehiculos = async (operaciones,lvehiculos,session = undefined) => {
   const promises = lvehiculos.map(async (vehiculo) => {
    const { vin, ...rest } = vehiculo
    const updatedVehiculo = Vehiculo.findOneAndUpdate(
    { vin: vin },
    { ...rest, modulos: operaciones },
    { session, new: true, runValidators: true }
    )
// Manualmente ejecutar las validaciones después de la actualización
  await updatedVehiculo.validate()

  return updatedVehiculo
  })
 const listaDeVehiculosGuardada = await Promise.all(promises)
 return listaDeVehiculosGuardada
}


este sitio solo acepta preguntas en la cual el contexto este explicado en idioma español.

Probablemente sea el Promise.all porque eso resuelve las promesas de forma concurrente (al mismo tiempo), tendrías que hacerlo de forma secuencial (una tras otra)

@PsychoMx a pesar de que OP aceptó tu edición: debe ser él mismo quien traduzca su pregunta.
